# Find command: Searching for executable files

Tags: find, executable

What type of parameter/flag can I use with the unix *find* command so that I search executables?

(if this question is better suited for another stackexchange forum, I welcome you telling me so)

p.s. If you know of one, I've been looking for a detailed (non-beginner) tutorial/screencast about grep and/or find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Portably, the following command looks for regular files that are executable by their owner:

```
find . -perm -700 -type f
```

With GNU find ≥4.3, you can use `-executable` instead of `-perm -700` to look for files that are executable by you.

Answer (score 6):

Rather unsurprisingly, `-executable`. From the man page:

> Matches files which are executable and directories which are searchable (in a file name resolution sense). This takes into account access control lists and other permissions  artefacts which the -perm test ignores

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
find /path -perm /u=x,g=x,o=x -type f
```

It looks through `/path`, finds user, global and other executables that are regular files.